# How do I change my password for Tox?

Tags: terminal, password

I use Tox (Tox.chat) for IM on my computer, linux OS. I would like to change my password. Does anyone know how to? I log in thru a terminal, but the command to change my password for my desktop terminal or firewall terminal, which is "passwd", does not work for changing the password in Tox.

Comment: Since nobody here seems to be using the same software as you, you may be better served by using the support email address found in the Tox FAQ: https://tox.chat/faq.html

Comment: I don't use Tox, but it seems to use some sort of public key authentication. If that is the case, perhaps a password is only used to protect your private key locally, and if the private key is in a standard format, you might be able to use tools like `openssl` to change the password on the private key.

Comment: Thanks. Tox doesn't seem to answer many/any questions in its list. TelcoM's comments are likely correct, thanks, but I don't know enough about 'openssl' to know how to begin that.